# Rotate animation android from top right,Bottom left, Bottom right in android?

Tags: android, animation, transformation

The below code helps me to rotate through left top edge of screen when swipe. can any one helps me how to rotate through remaining edges of the screen like top right edge, bottom right and left edges.
To be simple i need Rotate Page Transform as an animation for image view

```
RotateAnimation r=new RotateAnimation(130,0,90,180);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking,  can you elaborate?

Comment: I had an image view on activity when i swipe right it need to move out of the screen by animation with right top edge as coordinates and another image enters from the left with left top edge as coordinates, to be simple it should be like rotate Page transform(but i need animation for image view)

Answer (score 2):

You may use this code:

```
RotateAnimation r=new RotateAnimation(0,90);
RotateAnimation r=new RotateAnimation(180,270);
RotateAnimation r=new RotateAnimation(270,360);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need coordinates of imageview to rotate on particular edge you can get by using

```
     Rect rect = new Rect();
     imageview.getLocalVisibleRect(rect);
     int bottomimagevalue = rect.bottom;
     int rightimagevalue = rect.right;
```

Using this coordinated you can rotate image

```
 RotateAnimation r=new RotateAnimation(130,0,bottomimagevalue,rightimagevalue);
```

the above is example for rotating image from bottom right corner