# How to animate image View in android from its position to clicked position?

Tags: java, android, animation

There is **3 Textview** and **1 Imageview** in my layout. by this code, I can change the position of `Imageview` to move it on top of each `Textview` that clicked by user.Is there any way to move it by an `animation` from its position to clicked `Textview`?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DisplayMetrics screenSize = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(screenSize);
        screenWidth = screenSize.widthPixels;

        final ImageView greenBar = findViewById(R.id.green_bar);
        greenBar.getLayoutParams().width = screenWidth / 3;
        greenBar.setX(screenWidth * 2 /3);

        TextView leftText = findViewById(R.id.text_left);
        TextView rightText = findViewById(R.id.text_right);
        TextView middleText = findViewById(R.id.text_middle);

        leftText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                greenBar.setX(0);
            }
        });

        rightText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                greenBar.setX(screenWidth * 2 /3);
            }
        });

        middleText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                greenBar.setX(screenWidth /3);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Update** : I know I should use these constructors,but I dont know how to set these values!

```
TranslateAnimation(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
TranslateAnimation(int fromXType, float fromXValue, int toXType, float toXValue, int fromYType, float fromYValue, int toYType, float toYValue)
```

Comment: go through this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44954284/7226732] i m sure u will solve ur issue

Comment: @Mohammad thanks,but this is for rotation, not translate!